# Formatting Bad Text into a data frame using R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

How do I format `my_words` :

```
my_words = "June 29, 2019June 27, 2020June 29, 2019Net sales:   Products$46,529 $42,354 $170,598 $162,354"
```

Comment: This task is huge and messy, involving excessive amounts of regex. I don't think you can just say, here's my problem, solve it! You need to show at least some level of effort of your own! Here's is perhaps something to get you on track: `unlist(stringr::str_split(my_words, "(?<=Ended)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=\\d)\\s?(?=[A-Z])"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution. You might want to reference the cheat sheet of `stringr` package if you are not clear with the following regular expressions.

In short, I split the string by three *or* categories:

1. digit followed by alpha or blank
2. lower followed by upper, digit, or dollar
3. colon followed by upper

```
my_words = "Three Months EndedNine Months EndedJune 27, 2020June 29, 2019June 27, 2020June 29, 2019Net sales:   Products$46,529 $42,354 $170,598 $162,354    Services13,156 11,455 39,219 33,780 Total net sales59,685 53,809 209,817 196,134 Cost of sales:   Products32,693 29,473 116,089 109,758    Services4,312 4,109 13,461 12,297 Total cost of sales37,005 33,582 129,550 122,055 Gross margin22,680 20,227 80,267 74,079 Operating expenses:Research and development4,758 4,257 13,774 12,107 Selling, general and administrative4,831 4,426 14,980 13,667 Total operating expenses9,589 8,683 28,754 25,774 Operating income13,091 11,544 51,513 48,305 Other income/(expense), net46 367 677 1,305 Income before provision for income taxes13,137 11,911 52,190 49,610 Provision for income taxes1,884 1,867 7,452 8,040 Net income$11,253 $10,044 $44,738 $41,570 Earnings per share:Basic$2.61 $2.20 $10.25 $8.92 Diluted$2.58 $2.18 $10.16 $8.86 Shares used in computing earnings per share:Basic4,312,573 4,570,633 4,362,571 4,660,175 Diluted4,354,788 4,601,380 4,404,695 4,691,759"
my_words = stringr::str_split(my_words, "(?<=[:digit:])(?=[:alpha:]|[:blank:])|(?<=[:lower:])(?=[:upper:]|[:digit:]|\\$)|(?<=:)(?=[:upper:])")
my_words = stringr::str_trim(as.list(my_words[[1]]))
my_words
```